# phpmyadmin - How to hide "Server:" input of login screen

Tags: phpmyadmin

I don't need this input form because I got the selection. How can I remove this?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That field has been enabled by you (or someone) placing the line `$cfg['AllowArbitraryServer'] = true;` in the configuration file, config.inc.php. You can get rid of it by editing config.inc.php and removing that line (or setting it to false, which is the default). [Reference](https://docs.phpmyadmin.net/en/latest/config.html#cfg_AllowArbitraryServer)

Comment: Our docker container had PMA_ARBITRARY=1 somehow. Thank you!